# Redirecting users to different pages according to their id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to Redirecting users to different pages according to their id

mysql db user table like below
"username=admin", "id=1" & "username=user", "id=2"

I had two pages `index1.php` & `index2.php`. I need, when I login admin open `index1.php` & login user open `index2.php` page i try to below code, but always open one page.

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost:3308', 'root', '', 'inventory');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        if (md5($_POST['password']) !== $password) {
            echo "Password is invalid";
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$username' AND password_1 ='$password'";
        $sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM register WHERE username='$username' AND password_1 ='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $res = mysqli_num_rows($results);
        if ($res) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row["first_name"];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row["last_name"];
            header('location: index.php');
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code shown do you examine the ID value or redirect to `index1.php` or `index2.php`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($row["id"]==1)
{
  header('location: index1.php');
}
elseif($row["id"]==2)
{
  header('location: index2.php');
}
else
{
  header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Hello Arpit , Thanks for you respond , in this scenario, always open in index.php page